# Determine all x such that the power series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I know that the first step would be to use the ratio test. You would add a $+1$ to everywhere there is an n and then multiply that by the reciprocal of the original function but what would I do next after that?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-2)^n}{4^n\sqrt{n}}$$

How do I simplify the double fraction result after I set up the ratio test?

Comment: What do you mean what do I do next? That depends on what you get as the result of the ratio test. What does it say when the limit is greater than 1, less than 1 and equal to 1? Anyway, you should be a little bit more specific as to where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin how do I simplify the double fraction result after I set up the ratio test?

Comment: This doesn't converge for any $n$ as the denominator is zero when $n=0$.

Comment: welcome to MSE, kindly learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) to facilitate communication rather than attachign pictures. Also, always include explaination of where are you stuck when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $n$ should start at a number that's greater than zero because, as you probably know, you can't have zero in the denominator.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\left(\frac{(x-2)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{(x-2)^n}{4^n\sqrt{n}}\right)}\right|=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(x-2)\sqrt{n}}{4\sqrt{n+1}}\right|=
\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\\
\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=
\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|\cdot \sqrt{1-0}=
\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|.
$$

So, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{4^n\sqrt{n}}$ converges absolutely when:
$$
\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|<1\implies\\
|x-2|<4\implies -2<x<6.
$$

And the last thing you need to do is to figure out if the series converges at the endpoints $-2$ and $6$ because if $\left|\frac{x-2}{4}\right|=1$ (that happens precisely when $x=-2$ or $6$), the ratio test is inconclusive. If $x=-2$, the seires $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges by the alternating series test and if $x=6$, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges by the p-series test because in this case $p=\frac{1}{2}<1$.

Therefore, the interval of convergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{4^n\sqrt{n}}$ is $[-2,6)$ and its radius of convergence is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|x-2|}{4}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} < 1$$

Evaluate the limit on the left hand side and solve for $x$.

Also remember to check the boundary.

Alternating series test and $p$-series test are of interest to you.